# Can PowerBI be integrated with Azure Powershell

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

If I have Azure Powershell cmdlets, can their outputs be directly streamed to Power BI for rendering with visuals?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please explan a little more what you are trying to do ?

Comment: If I run a cmdlet such as Get-AzureRmResource which lists resource properties as ouput, can it stream that output directly into PowerBI as data source instead of having to store the output onto an Azure table storage?  PowerBI can access Azure table storage.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a look at following link:

https://www.sqlshack.com/connect-query-power-bi-azure-using-powershell/

which may give you a good basic introduction on what you possibly can do with powershell & PowerBI. Range of features and method options may vary depending on cmdlets powershell library package you install. Some options may still run but are listed as deprecated... Also Power BI REST API seems to be the new main driving engine in most scenarios, so you may need to priorly proceed with an AAD App Registration first in order to get any further expected result. Hope this helps.